# ]] characters stop Eclipse console from working

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, console, glassfish

I have a Java EE 7, SE 8 project (glassfish 4.1, JSF, JPA, EJB)(Eclipse Neon). It used to work properly. Now when I start glassfish it tells me that a certificate has expired.

```
2018-10-17T19:35:58.516+0000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2018-10-17T19:35:59.920+0000|Severe: The SSL certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 135786214035069526348186531221551781468391756233528066061569654028671100866720352830303278016129003918213826297308054231261658522889438712013757624116391437358730449661353175673177742307421061340003741057138887918110217006515773038453829253517076741780039735595086881329494037450587568122088113584549069375417
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Aug 22 16:41:51 UTC 1998,
               To: Wed Aug 22 16:41:51 UTC 2018]
  Issuer: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    35def4cf]
Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: 1.2.840.113533.7.65.0 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 0D 30 0B 1B 05 56 33   2E 30 63 03 02 06 C0     ..0...V3.0c....
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 48 E6 68 F9 2B D2 B2 95   D7 47 D8 23 20 10 4F 33  H.h.+....G.# .O3
0010: 98 90 9F D4                                        ....
]
]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [CN=CRL1, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US]
```

Now glassfish still starts and works properly, so is the project. The problem is that nothing is displayed in the console after the last line above. However when I open the log file server.log every is being written there.

What I noticed is that printing these two characters cause the problem ]]

This is from the log file:

```
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [CN=CRL1, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false…

I tried to print those lines to see if Eclipse would print them and it did print them.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false");
        System.out.println("CRLDistributionPoints [");
        System.out.println("  [DistributionPoint:");
        System.out.println("     [CN=CRL1, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US]");
        System.out.println("]]");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false");

    }
```

So what is the problem? And how can I fix it?

I tried to list certificates to remove the one that expired, using keytool –list . However I get this keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Name\.keystore

Note: same thing happens in Eclipse Photon.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with eclipse or the bracket characters. It's application specific so nobody will answer this with authority but there's probably something wrong with having the expired certificate. You should portably look for the keystore

Comment: I will try remove java and re-install it and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I fix it by going to
  `D:\Dev\Servers\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config`
- listing certificates using `keytool -list -keystore cacerts.jks -v`
- getting the alias for the certificate
- then removing using `keytool -delete -alias equifaxsecureca -keystore
  cacerts.jks`